# how can I monkey-patch pathlib on python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 to get same functionality like in python 3.8?

Tags: python, upgrade, python-3.7, python-3.8, pathlib

I use `pathlib` in my software for library development -
but unfortunately my travis matrix brakes, because on some older python versions (3.5 - 3.7)
the `pathlib.Path` is not compatible with the newest 3.8 Version.

for instance, following will work on python 3.8, but not on 3.6, 3.7 etc. :

```
>>> path_test_file = pathlib.Path('./tests/mytest.txt')
>>> path_test_file.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

Is there a convenient way to upgrade the `pathlib` library via requirements.txt, `pip`, etc ?

I tried also to monkey-patch the `pathlib` of older versions, but failed miserably.

As @jakub points out, of course there are programmatic solutions for that, like :

```
if path_test_file.exits(): 
    path_test_file.unlink()

# or:
try:
    path_test_file.unlink()
except Exception:
    pass
```

that is really all clear and does not need an answer - but I don't want to clutter my code like that.
I would rather like to include some module and monkey-patch `pathlib.Path` if needed, and leave all other code as it is - and still be compatible with older python versions.

Maybe I should bump up https://github.com/KenKundert/extended_pathlib/blob/master/extended_pathlib.py

Comment: Try using https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/

Comment: `pathlib` is part of the Python standard library, I don't think it can by updated separately.

Comment: @jakub As of January 1 2020, this repository will no longer receive any further updates, as Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: @jakub, pathlib2 also have seriouse problems with unicode chars on windows, that is no option

Comment: in that case, i would suggest writing something that works across the python versions you need. in the case of `Path.unlink(missing_ok=True)`, for example, you can use a `try-except` to account for missing files and then you can remove the `missing_ok` keyword, which is new in python 3.8.

Comment: @jakup - thats clear. But I dont want to clutter my code with `try-except` when it can be so much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the python3.8 pathlib file to a new package, and tweaked a few lines, so it can behave like pathlib.

Now You can use all the python3.8 pathlib goodies also in 3.6, 3.7

You might find it on [github](https://travis-ci.org/github/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x/)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>